SSRS REST API to get CatalogItems in a hidden folder
Using the SSRS REST API, how do I get a datasource named "my_data_source" if it is in a hidden folder?
I have discovered that I can find the folder itself using $filter=(hidden eq false or hidden eq true), but that trick doesn't seem to work for items inside the folder.

By observing the API calls made by the SSRS Management site, I discovered the CatalogItemByPath() endpoint which I did not find in the Swagger documentation.
e.g.
GET https://myServer.somewhere.com/Reports/api/v2.0/CatalogItemByPath(path='/MyFolder/MySubfolder')
